# File format of CF10-jpg

Tags: file-format

While working on a tool that allows to exchange images of several third-party applications and thus creating individual "skins" for those applications, I have stumbled across a jpg-format about which I cannot seem to find any decent informations.

When looking at it in a hex-editor, it starts with the tag "CF10". Searching the internet has only provided a tool that is able to handle these kind of files, without any additional informations.

Does anyone have any further informations about this type of jpg-format?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26442162/decryption-of-png-and-jpg-files for decoding an example file.

Answer (score 2):

[`file(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/file) should give you some useful information.  You can also use ImageMagick's [`identify(1)`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/identify.php) program (optionally with the `-verbose` option) to get even more details about the file.  See the example on that page for a good idea of what information it provides.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try and see what the [Droid](http://droid.sourceforge.net/) identification tool says about that file.

Answer (score 0):

CF stands for "Compression Factor". CF-10 means factor ten, and I don't think it's different from any "standard" jpeg.

Comment: I would expect to find the usual JPEG markers (0xff) in the files, which is not the case. Is the "compression factor" linked to the jpeg-file or does it refer to another compression algorithm used to compress the image itself?

Answer (score 0):

DROID gives it as being a "JTIP (JPEG Tiled Image Pyramid)". Some info from http://www.bcr.org/cdp/digitaltb/digital_imaging/formats.html :

> JTIP (JPEG Tiled Image Pyramid) is similar to GridPrix. It offers multiple layers of higher and higher resolutions. Each layer is further divided into tiles. A user can zoom into these tiles, or request a corresponding tile at a higher resolution.