# Decryption of .png and .jpg files

Tags: encryption, png, jpeg, assets

I'm trying to modify graphic assets of the software I'm using (for aesthetic puroposess, I guess it's hard to do something harmful with graphic assets) but developer encrypted them. I'm not sure why he decided to do that since I used and modified a bunch of similar softwares and developers of those didn't bother (as I can see no reason why encrypting those assets would be necessary).

So anyway here are examples of those encrypted graphic assets:

http://www.mediafire.com/view/sx2yc0w5wkr9m2h/avatars_50-alpha.jpg
http://www.mediafire.com/download/i4fc52438hkp55l/avatars_80.png

Is there a way of decrypting those? If so how should I go about this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/113641/file-format-of-cf10-jpg

Comment: The characters in your first example have a too high repetition count to be encrypted. Maybe you cannot read it, but that's more a question of encoding/decoding of images.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The header "CF10" seems to be a privately added signature to signify the rest of the file is "encoded". This is a very simple XOR encoding: `xor 8Dh` was the first value I tried, and I got it right first time too. The reasoning behind *trying* that as the first value is that the value `8D` occurs very frequently in the first 100 bytes-or-so, where they typically could be lots of zeroes.

"Decrypting" is thus very straightforward: if a file starts with the four bytes `CF10`, remove them and apply `xor 8Dh` on the rest of the file. Decoding the files show the first "JPG" is in fact a tiny PNG image (and not a very interesting one to boot), the second is indeed a PNG file:

[image: decoded image]

The file extension may or may not be the *original* file extension; the one sample called ".jpg" is in fact also a PNG file, as can be seen by its header signature.

The following quick-and-dirty C source will *decode* the images. The same program can be adjusted to *encode* them as well, because the `xor` operation is exactly the same. The only thing needed is add a bit of logic flow:

1. read the first 4 bytes (maximum) of the input file and test if this forms the string `CF10`
2. if not, the file is not encoded:
   a. write `CF10` to the output file
   b. encode the image by applying `xor 8Dh` on each byte
3. if so,
   b. decode the image by applying `xor 8Dh` on each byte.

As you can see, there is no "3a" and both "b" steps are the same.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef MAX_PATH
    #define MAX_PATH    256
#endif

#define INPUTPATH "c:\\documents"
#define OUTPUTPATH ""

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *inp, *outp;
    int i, encode_flag = 0;
    char filename_buffer[MAX_PATH];
    char sig[] = "CF10", *ptr;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf ("usage: decode [input] [output]\n");
        return -1;
    }

    filename_buffer[0] = 0;
    if (!strchr(argv[1], '/') && !strchr(argv[1], 92) && !strchr(argv[1], ':'))
        strcpy (filename_buffer, INPUTPATH);
    strcat (filename_buffer, argv[1]);

    inp = fopen (filename_buffer, "rb");
    if (inp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("bad input file '%s'\n", filename_buffer);
        return -2;
    }
    ptr = sig;
    while (*ptr)
    {
        i = fgetc (inp);
        if (*ptr != i)
        {
            encode_flag = 1;
            break;
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    if (encode_flag)
    {
        /* rewind file because we already read some bytes */
        fseek (inp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        printf ("encoding input file: '%s'\n", filename_buffer);
    } else
        printf ("decoding input file: '%s'\n", filename_buffer);

    filename_buffer[0] = 0;
    if (!strchr(argv[2], '/') && !strchr(argv[2], 92) && !strchr(argv[2], ':'))
        strcpy (filename_buffer, OUTPUTPATH);
    strcat (filename_buffer, argv[2]);

    outp = fopen (filename_buffer, "wb");
    if (outp == NULL)
    {
        printf ("bad output file '%s'\n", filename_buffer);
        return -2;
    }
    printf ("output file: '%s'\n", filename_buffer);

    if (encode_flag)
        fwrite (sig, 1, 4, outp);
    do
    {
        i = fgetc(inp);
        if (i != EOF)
            fputc (i ^ 0x8d, outp);
    } while (i != EOF);
    fclose (inp);
    fclose (outp);
    printf ("all done. bye bye\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Haven't tried it yet but from what I can see above it's kinda obvious it will work. You sir are a beast. Thank you so much. I am gonna mark your post as solution but I might have follow up questions if you be so kind to answer them later. Once again sir. You rock.

Comment: Ok I thought I would be able to do this by myself but unfortunately my programming knowledge is super limited (I only know some c# and JavaScript basics, I used mostly my graphic design skills to modify other similar softwares that I mentioned above and didn't had their files encoded) to the point that I am not even sure how to compile C program... Could you explain how excatly should I use the code you provided above? (how to compile it, how to "show" this program file that I want to decrypt etc.?). I would be very gateful.

Comment: Sorry, that is *way* too broad for a Stack Overflow answer. Use Google, please. After compiling its usgae is shown when no arguments are given.

Comment: Fair enough. I think couple hours of research should do the trick. Thanks again for your help:)

Comment: Ok I did my research. I know how to compile and build C code in Visual Studio now. I still don't understand C syntax on a lvl that let's me understand your code thou. But since my last question was too broad I am gonna ask specific one now:) How to modify the code you posted above to predefine the path to file I want to decrypt (e.g. c:\documents\fileIWantToDecrypt.png). That should be easier than making program ask the user to input the path.

Comment: Added default path construction for you (it's just some strings manipulation). Just fill in the `#define`s (and don't forget to double backslashes inside a string). Welcome to C!

Comment: One last question. Can you tell me exactly how to modify this code to encode files instead of decoding them? I know you mentioned it above but i still don't understand C syntax well enough to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so when it comes to practical usage of the code provided by @Jongware that was unclear to me - I figured it out with some help:)

1. I compiled the code using Visual Studio (you can find guides on how to do that, basically create new Visual C++ project and in Project -> Project Propeties choose C/C++ -> All options and  Compile as C Code (/TC)).
2. Then I opened program in command prompt using parameter "program encrypted_file decrypted_file".

Thanks a lot for help Jongware!